# Calling a python script from another python script

Tags: python-3.x

I have two python scripts named start_worker.py and train_worker.py. I want to call train_worker.py from start_worker.py. Both the scripts are placed under same directory. The python script start_worker.py is following-

```
#start_worker.py
*some code....*
python3 train_worker.py 3
*some code ..*
```

Now when I am running python start_worker 0
I am getting an error, "No such file or directory at train_worker.py"
Is using execfile() is a solution?? Please suggest a solution..

Comment: you need to import that file in begining of your `start_worker.py` script like , `import train_worker` to be able to use functions in that script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put this in main.py:**

> ## !/usr/bin/python import yoursubfile

**Put this in yoursubfile.py**

> ## !/usr/bin/python
>
> print "hello";

Run it:

> python main.py

OUTPUT:

> hello

Thus main.py runs yoursubfile.py

In your case i feel you havnt import the file.

> import filename
> print filename.py

if in folder or something .

> from folder import filename
> print filename.py